# Number Theory: Prove for all $1\leq n \in \mathbb{N}$ $F_n \mid 2^{F_n}-2$ with $F_n$ is Fermat numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

Number Theory: Prove for all $1\leq n \in \mathbb{N}$ $F_n \mid 2^{F_n}-2$ with $F_n$ is **Fermat numbers**

Follow the following sections They will guide you in proof

1. Use polynomial division to prove that $2^{2^{n+1}}-1\mid2^{F_n-1}-1$.
2. Use polynomial division to prove that $F_n\mid2^{2^{n+1}}-1$.
3. Draw the conclusion from these two sections.

***Attempt:***

if $2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ divide $2^{F_n-1}-1$ and $F_n$ divide $2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ so $F_n$ divide $2^{F_n-1}-1$

and i have no idea how to make it happen.

Comment: Do you know what $F_n$ is?  Do you see how 3. follows from 1. and 2.?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner of course I know what $F_n$ is . and if $2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ divide $2^{F_n-1}-1$ and $F_n$ divide $2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ so $F_n$ divide $2^{F_n-1}-1$

Comment: do you see why that means $F_n$ divides $2^{F_n}-2$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. $2^{2^{2^n}}-1=(2^{2^{n+1}}-1)(2^{2^{2^n}-2^{n+1}}+2^{2^{2^n}-2\cdot2^{n+1}}+2^{2^{2^n}-3\cdot2^{n+1}}+\cdots+2^{{2^{n+1}}}+1)$
2. $2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ is the difference of two squares
3. if $a|b$ and $b|c$ then $a|2c$

Comment: for 1. how do u factorize $2^{2^{2^n}}-1=(2^{2^{n+1}}-1)(2^{2^{2^n}-2^{n+1}}+2^{2^{2^n}-2\cdot2^{n+1}}+2^{2^{2^n}-3\cdot2^{n+1}}+\cdots+2^{{2^{n+1}}}+1)$ ?? how you can prove that $2^{2^{2^n}}-1$ is equal to the right hand side.

Comment: 2.  you can explain what u mean difference of two squares ?

Comment: By d.o.t.s., I mean $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$